# ES6 create separate arrays based on string values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array with the following data:

```
[ { download: 'Test1', user: 'email@email.com' },
  { download: 'Test2', user: 'email2@email.com' },
  { download: 'Test1', user: 'email3@email.com' },
  { download: 'Test1', user: 'email4@email.com' }
]
```

I'm trying to create 2 arrays based on the `download` string. So for example an array of:

```
[ { download: 'Test1', user: 'email@email.com' },
  { download: 'Test1', user: 'email3@email.com' },
  { download: 'Test1', user: 'email4@email.com' }
]
```

and another array:

```
[
  { download: 'Test2', user: 'email2@email.com' },
]
```

What's the best way of doing this? I can't filter by doing a `download === 'Test2'` as the `download` string can always change and be different.

Would this be a job for `.reduce()` ?

Comment: yes, use reduce() to create an object keyed by the values in download, where the value associated with each key is the array of object that match the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reduce and object as accumulator, club elements based on download property value

```js
let data = [ { download: 'Test1', user: 'email@email.com' },{ download: 'Test2', user: 'email2@email.com' },{ download: 'Test1', user: 'email3@email.com' },{ download: 'Test1', user: 'email4@email.com' }]

let final = data.reduce( (op,inp) => {
  let {download}  = inp
  op[download] = op[download] || []
  op[download].push(inp)
  return op
},{})

console.log(final)
```